# Is there a way to escape % while using call in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, escaping, call

This is my first batch script. I was trying to escape % char so that is not used as variable. Double %% works when using start, but when I use %% with call it input en empty space and function missing parameter.

**Is there a way to escape % while using call ?**

```
call wp rewrite structure %%postname%% << FAILED
start wp rewrite structure %%postname%% << OK
```

I was just wondering why is that same statement with "start" worked as expected and "call" was missing an argument. Both were escaping percent sign using additional % char.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I presume your "OK" line is OK because you want the literal `%postname%`, and you recognize that percent literals must be escaped by doubling within a batch file.

If you don't double the percents, then `%postname%` is expanded to the value of environment variable postname (or empty string if not defined).

CALL causes percents to be evaluated twice. The first round of percent expansion converts `%%postname%%` into `%postname%`. That is what you want. But then the second round initiated by CALL causes `%postname%` to be expanded to the variable value.

The solution is simple, double the percents a second time:

```
call wp rewrite structure %%%%postname%%%%
```

Comment: Good question... Perhaps the downvoter just didn't understood the answer... **`:(`**  I just upvoted it to compensate!

Answer (score 3):

Did you try

```
call wp rewrite structure %%%%postname%%%%
```